# Why do people still backup their movies as mkv today?

Tags: mp4, video-encoding, matroska

Why anyone would use the matroska container when mp4 is way more compatible and has at least all mkv features as a container?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: untrue. superior compatibility of mp4 is only on a network level - mostly because mp4 its outdated but still fits basic needs.

Comment: "way more compatible" with what? Players, absolutely! Codecs? absolutely not! Royalties? depends on how legally adverse you are.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that mkv has more features than mp4 based on the documentation on the handbrake program website. May be good for you to read through it as well if you haven't already.